# UIStepper over riding the UILabel values in Custom Cell in iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview, label, uistepper

I have a `UITableViewController` which consists of a `TableView` and a `UILabel`. `UITableViewSource` feeds data to the `TableView` through custom UITableViewCell. `UITableViewCell` consists of a Stepper which can add items and the Label holds that value.

I want to update the `UILabel` in `UIViewController` when the user taps on the Stepper and i cannot seem to get that to work...

Any help/tips are greatly appreciated! Here is sample code from my test project, there is a bunch of unused code but this is just a test so i let it be there.

Thanks,

The Code is

My Custom Cell Class is "StepperDetailsCell".

```
@interface StepperDetailsCell : UITableViewCell
@property (nonatomic,weak) id <StepperDetailsCellDelegate> delegate;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imagegroceries;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIStepper *objstepper;
@property (strong,nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblsteppervalue;


   -(IBAction)stepperclicked:(UIStepper*)sender;

@end
```

and My table view class is named as "SecondViewController"

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"Cell";

    cell = (StepperDetailsCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil){

        cell = (StepperDetailsCell *)[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    }

    [cell.imagegroceries setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[[self.didSelectedImages sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];

    [cell.objstepper addTarget:self action:@selector(stepperValuechanges:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    cell.lblsteppervalue.text = [self.quantityArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    return cell;
}
```

pragma mark - Stepper Action Method

```
-(void)stepperValuechanges:(UIStepper *)sender{

    CGPoint stepperPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.tableView];
    indexPath1 = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:stepperPosition];

    if (indexPath1 != nil )
    {
        float val = sender.value;
        valueInt = (int)val;

        [self.quantityArr replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath1.row withObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",valueInt]];
        NSLog(@"%@",self.quantityMDict);
    }

    [self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

Here, Everything is working properly,but whenever new cell is loading from bottom of tableview, then that time new cell stepper act as disappeared cell stepper.

Comment: There is no code in your question.

Comment: @Nitin Gohel , Now i added my code

Answer (score 0):

Finally After 3 days I solved my problem.

Just set the value for UIStepper before firing the action of the UIStepper Object to the corresponding Controller Object like the following way..

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

```
static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"Cell";

cell = (StepperDetailsCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

if (cell == nil){

    cell = (StepperDetailsCell *)[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

}

[cell.imagegroceries setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[[self.didSelectedImages sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
```

// I just set the previous value(this value, I am taken from the array named "quantityArr") to corresponding stepper, before firing the action to the controller object from the stepper object. That's it..

```
[cell.objstepper setValue:[[self.quantityArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] doubleValue]];

[cell.objstepper addTarget:self action:@selector(stepperValuechanges:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

cell.lblsteppervalue.text = [self.quantityArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


return cell;
```

}